# What is the approach to alfresco file upload from api?

Tags: java, file-upload, alfresco

I need to make an extension to Alfresko (SDK 3.0) that should upload file from an external source.

I've managed to create a simple tutorial extension (https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/tasks/dev-extensions-share-tutorials-add-menuitem-create-menu.html) but i can't even guess how can i integrate a file upload logic there?!?

The main goal of extension is to uplaod a file, that is achieved from a simple office scanner. Scanning job is expected to be dealt with by a separate application, that after the job's done should return file via rest API.

I'm new to Alfresco, so could anyone please advice the approach i should use (or maybe point to an example) for calling and recieving data in Alfresco extension?

Comment: Just use CMIS or the Rest API and send the file straight to the repo?

Comment: How Can I achive Using Java Rest API?

Comment: Just use webDAV which will sync your local folder with Alfresco repo https://docs.alfresco.com/6.0/concepts/troubleshoot-webdav.html